# can ngflow file slice and chunk support chrome25 in cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp

I have a web site, use `ngflow` to upload my files, `ngflow` use HTML5 fileapi, if a file is big, it slite chunks.

I use `CefSharp` browes my site, but chrome in `CefSharp` is old version of 25, if the file size is larger than the chunk size (size of each slice), the Content-Length in XHR header will still be the unsliced file size, not the chunk size. Who can help me?

Comment: Latest version of `CefSharp` is `51.0.0` (Which is based on `Chromium 51`), older versions are no longer supported.

Comment: hi ,billal ,my cef must run on xp operating system，so i no chose but older version of 37.do you kown html5  file api?

Comment: 49 is the newsest version that will run on XP, requires VC++ 2013.

Comment: thank you very much